Soft question: How do you remember/intuit these conditional entropy inequalities?
We have a probability space $(X, \mathcal{B}, |\cdot|)$ along with three finite $\sigma$ subalgebras $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D} \subset \mathcal{B}$.
Given the finite sigma algebra $\mathcal{A}$, the collection of sets
\begin{equation}
A_x := \bigcap\left\lbrace A \in \mathcal{A} : x \in A \right\rbrace
\end{equation}
gives a partition, $\xi(\mathcal{A})$ of $X$ by sets in $\mathcal{A}$. We have similar partitions for the other finite sigma algebras.
Definition: (Entropy)  We define 'entropy'
\begin{equation}
h_{\mu}(\mathcal{A}) := -\sum_{A \in \xi(\mathcal{A})} |A| \log|A|
\end{equation}
with convention that $0\cdot \log 0 = 0$.
Definition: (Conditional Entropy): We define entropy of $\mathcal{A}$ conditioned on $\mathcal{B}$ to be
\begin{equation}
h_{\mu}(\mathcal{A}|\mathcal{B}) := -\sum_{B \in \mathcal{\xi(\mathcal{B})}} |B| \sum_{A \in \xi(\mathcal{A})} \frac{|A\cap B|}{|B|} \log \frac{|A \cap B|}{|B|}
\end{equation}
These definitions are reported to be 'intuitively' capturing the notion of uncertainty (entropy) with respect to a poll/experiment (the partition or finite sigma algebra) being used to detect the best policy/candidate (the set with the largest probability) - See the comment after Theorem 4.3 in Walter's book on Ergodic Theory where he says 'the reader should think about the intuitive meaning of each statement'.
Question: What is some reasonable intuition to remember/justify the following two inequalities?

If $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{C}$ then $H(\mathcal{A}|\mathcal{D}) \leq H(\mathcal{C}|\mathcal{D})$.
If $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{D}$ then $H(\mathcal{A}|\mathcal{C}) \geq H(\mathcal{A}|\mathcal{D})$.


In my humble opinion translating the statements to partitions leads to heuristics that are easier to remember. Recall that your map that transforms a sub-$\sigma$-algebra to a measurable partition is an isomorphism (for $X$ standard measurable) between the category of sub-$\sigma$-algebras of $\mathcal(B)$ (with inclusions as morphisms) and the category of measurable partitions (with refinements as morphisms); the inverse of your map is saturation (for $\xi$ a partition $\mathcal{A}_\xi$ is the sub-$\sigma$-algebra of subsets that are unions of cells of $\xi$). (There is some fine print about all this, and even though all this is folklore it might be that there is no complete account; though see my thesis https://alpuzman.github.io/research/uzman_dissertation_final.pdf , p. 28 for more details.)

A partition heuristically is a pixellation; the finer the partition the smaller the pixels and hence the higher resolution one can see. (see also the discussion at Where are the units of the box counting fractal dimension?). Based on the isomorphism mentioned above, one has that $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{B}$ if and only if $\beta$ refines $\alpha$, which heuristically means that the information content of $\beta$ is larger.


If $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{C}$ then $H(\mathcal{A}|\mathcal{D}) \leq H(\mathcal{C}|\mathcal{D})$.


Heuristically, $\gamma$ contains more information than $\alpha$, which is true no matter what one knows already (modeled by $\delta$). "The more detailed the more surprising."


If $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{D}$ then $H(\mathcal{A}|\mathcal{C}) \geq H(\mathcal{A}|\mathcal{D})$.


Heuristically, $\delta$ contains more information than $\gamma$, so given either pixellation, if one obtains access to a new pixellation $\alpha$, the amount of information gain will be less if one knew already $\delta$ as opposed to $\gamma$. "The wiser the less surprised."

To make these ideas more rigorous it might be instructive to consider entropy (conditional or otherwise) as the expectation of a certain information function.
As a final note I would highly recommend Rényi's A Diary on Information Theory for more heuristics.

Thank you! I will take a closer look at your answer + references.

I believe the key underlying intuition is the fact that mutual information cannot increase when we process data. I.e. if we have three random variables: $X, Y, Z$ such that $Z=f(Y)$ then:
$$
I(X,Y) \geq I(X,Z)
$$
Here is my intuitive proof for $1$. If $A \subset C$ then that means that the atomic events of $C$ are subsets of those of $A$. We can then write a random variables which identifies which atomic event of $A$ we are in as a function of a similar random variable identifying which atomic event of $C$ we are in.
If the events of $C$ are more precise, then they provide more information / have more entropy associated to them.
For $2$, I think a similar argument can be constructed, but I don't quite see all the details.
